# Why $\langle x,x\rangle - 2\langle x,y\rangle + \langle y,y\rangle = \langle x,x\rangle + \langle y,y\rangle$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

To be specific: I need to prove that $||\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}||=\sqrt{(||\mathbf{x}||^2+||\mathbf{y}||^2)}$, where we know that $\mathbf{x}\perp\mathbf{y}$ in an inner product space (hence not necessarily in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

I reach the point where $||\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}||=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle -2\langle x,y\rangle+\langle y,y\rangle}$. But my question is: Why does the term $-2\langle x,y\rangle$ cancel? I know that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ this is because of the Pythagorean Law (at least when $2\langle x,y\rangle$ is positive), but I am a bit more confused in this case, since it's not specific in what space we are.

Thank you!

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle` for delimiters, not `<` and `>`.

Comment: Hint: What does $\mathbf{x} \perp \mathbf{y}$ mean in this context?

Comment: With homework when you get stuck it's worth checking to see if you used all the assumptions given. Here you have expanded the inner product correctly but haven't used that the vectors given are perpendicular.

Comment: Have you used all the assumptions?  If you haven't used all the givens, then you might want to look there.

Comment: Note that you should also use boldface in "$\langle\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\rangle$", etc., as they are the same vectors as before. One would not usually think that $\mathbf{x}$ and $x$ represent the same object, because of the difference in typeface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By assumption, $x \perp y$ which is defined as $\langle x, y\rangle =0$.
Further, $||x||^2 = \langle x, x\rangle$.